# what's the best way to perfom response marshalling in flask?

Tags: python, flask, marshalling

I'm trying to create an API using flask, my goal is to have an hierarchy like so:

```
.
├── app.py
└── models/
    ├── schemas/
    │   └── greating_schema.py
    └── routes/
        └── greating_route.py
```

my goal is to have one *route* file for each endpoint in order to handle different request (get,put,post) and one *schema* for each endpoint in order to handle each data going through a request and/or response.

*app.py*

```py
import sys
from flask import Flask, url_for
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from apispec import APISpec
from apispec.ext.marshmallow import MarshmallowPlugin
from flask_apispec.extension import FlaskApiSpec

from Models.routes import greating_route

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update({
    'APISPEC_SPEC': APISpec(
        title='Health API',
        version='v1',
        plugins=[MarshmallowPlugin()],
        openapi_version='2.0.0'
    ),
    'APISPEC_SWAGGER_URL': '/doc/',
    'APISPEC_SWAGGER_UI_URL': '/doc-ui/'
})


api = Api(app)
docs = FlaskApiSpec(app)


api.add_resource(greating_route, '/')

docs.register(greating_route)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(DEBUG=True)
```

*greating_route.py*

```py
from flask_restful import Resource
class greating_route(Ressource)
    def get(self):
        return {'message': 'hello world'}

    def post(self, **kwargs):
        return {'message': 'hello'+kwargs['name']
```

I wonder how to modify the route to add the handling of the get response, for example making sure the *get* and *post* 'message' isn't longer than 20 and for the *post* request argument 'name' to be a string from a given list? and storing those schemas into Models/schemas/greating_schema.py

can you help me understand how to do that ?